# Zebra ZPL II QR Code "changes" position after printing a Bar Code

Tags: barcode, qr-code, zpl, barcode-printing, zpl-ii

I'm having a problem with ZPL code. When I send to the printer the following code:

```
`JA
`HS

^XA^JMA^XZ
^XA^JZN^XZ
^XA^CI0^XZ
^XA^PRC^XZ
`HS

^XA^POI^XZ
^XA^PW744^XZ
^XA^LH12,12
^FO660,384^AAN,36,10^FDL2^FS
^FO12,12^BY2,3^BQN,2,4^FVLM,B5500QR Code Content^FS^BY2,3
^MCN
^PQ1
^XZ
`HS

^XA^XZ^XA^MCY^XZ^XA^JMA^XZ
`HS
```

The printer prints a QR Code correctly. Then, in other label, I print the following Barcode:

```
`JA
`HS

^XA^JMA^XZ
^XA^JZN^XZ
^XA^CI0^XZ
^XA^PRC^XZ
`HS

^XA^PON^XZ
^XA^PW744^XZ
^XA^LH12,12
^FO84,204^BY,,0,72^BCN,72,N,N,N,N^FV>9Fixed text 1^FS^BY2,3
^MCN
^PQ1
^XZ
`HS

^XA^XZ^XA^MCY^XZ^XA^JMA^XZ
`HS
```

The barcode is also printed correctly but, if I try to print the QR Code again, using the same code as before, the QR Code it's not on the position it should be (FO12,12).

If I restart the printer, the QR Code is printed correctly again. This problem only occurs when I print a barcode. If I print text, box, images or lines the error doesn't happen.

Did anyone have a similar problem? I found this thread on the Zebra support site https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=forums&topic=021724cd8df90131764a436d007b1f with a similar problem but their solution (use BY2,3 to restore the default) didn't work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to send all tags between ^xa and ^xz. On one printer I had issue that this printer stored some commands in its memory.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. For now I'm waiting for the Zebra Suport to give an update. I sent them this question, they "escalated" the issue but haven't responded back yet.

Comment: Also, as a temporary workaround, we have a .bat file that sends the "JR" command to the printer. This command works almost the same as restarting the printer, so the user clicks on the bat file before asking to print the label.

Answer (score 2):

hey faced similar issue and found the solution this is happening due "BY" tag that was set for barcode as per ZPL guide

> Once a ^BY command is entered into a label format, it stays in effect
>   until another ^BY command is encountered.

so the height we set for barcode is being used for QR too !! try changing code to below

```
`JA
`HS

^XA^JMA^XZ
^XA^JZN^XZ
^XA^CI0^XZ
^XA^PRC^XZ
`HS

^XA^POI^XZ
^XA^PW744^XZ
^XA^LH12,12
^FO660,384^AAN,36,10^FDL2^FS
^FO12,12^BY2,3,0^BQN,2,4^FVLM,B5500QR Code Content^FS^BY2,3
^MCN
^PQ1
^XZ
`HS

^XA^XZ^XA^MCY^XZ^XA^JMA^XZ
`HS
```